# Fonts not recognized in mapbox tile in osmdroid

Tags: android, mapbox, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid to using map in my simple application and using `mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8` as a `TileSource`:

```
tileSource.setAccessToken("******");
tileSource.setMapboxMapid("mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8");
mapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

But fonts on map is not known like this:

[image]

Look at font's of place?

Comment: Is this happening everywhere or only in some places? I mean is it a problem with all languages / alphabets or only with some of them? (Latin, versus cyrillic, versus arabic etc.)

Comment: It seems just my place have a problem.I am from Iran and my language is Persian @JosefAdamcik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Osmdroid library supports only bitmap tiles at the moment. Mapbox supports [both vector and bitmap tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#maps). That means, that the broken text had to be rendered improperly at the mapbox side. Unfortunatelly you cannot do anything to fix that in your android application.

You should contact mapbox and report the problem to them. Apparently their bitmap tiles for `mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8` are not able to display Persian alphabet properly and I am sure they are not aware of that. Go to this link: https://www.mapbox.com/contact/support/#bug/map_api (you have to be logged in into your Mapbox account)  and upload the screenshot you provided here. You can also copy the description of the error from my response and add some information about the location of the screenshot. You can also add a link to this SO question.

Comment: Thanks dude.I report this problem to them. @JosefAdamcik